# Change label text based on file upload control inside repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file, upload, repeater

I have file upload and label control in a repeater. The problem is whenever a file is uploaded, I want to assign name of the uploaded file to a label inside repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID">
     <HeaderTemplate>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""><img src="../images/upload.png" alt="" style="position:absolute;cursor:pointer;"/></asp:Label>
      <asp:FileUpload ID="PhotoUpload" runat="server" CssClass="uplodfile" Style="padding: 0px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 20px;" />
      <asp:Label ID="lblFilePath" Text="" runat="server" Style="vertical-align: inherit; padding: 0px 5px;"></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Can anybody assist me how to achieve this?

Comment: thats a backend thing. Just extract the file name and assign to the label in the relevant event function.

Comment: using Repeater_ItemDataBound?

Answer (score 0):

You can use FindControl.

```
protected void PhotoUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = Repeater1.Items[0].FindControl("Label1") as Label;
    lbl.Text = "Label found!";
}
```